# Most likely value of k

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

A while ago I got this question on my exam, anyone got an idea how to solve this?

Smarties are a chocolate candy that come in k different colors. Suppose that
we do not know k.

a. 
We draw three smarties from a box and observe two different colors. What is the
most likely value for k0, given the smarties we have drawn.

Answer: 2

b.
We draw a fourth smartie and find a third color. What is now the most likely value
for k0, given the smarties we have drawn.

Answer: 5

Comment: I think you need to impose a prior probability distribution on k. Maybe an exponential distribution? Then you can apply bayes rule. But the question does not have a correct answer as it is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a), the probability of drawing two different colours in a selection of $3$ is
$$\binom{3}{1} k(k-1)(\frac{1}{k})^3 = \frac{3k(k-1)}{k^3}= \frac{3}{k}-\frac{3}{k^2}$$
The maximum value of this probability occurs when $\frac{d}{dk} \bigg(\frac{3}{k}-\frac{3}{k^2}\bigg)=0 \Rightarrow k=2$ and hence the most likely value of $k$ is $2$.

For part (b), the probability of finding a third different colour after drawing $3$ in part (a) is given by
$$(\frac{3}{k}-\frac{3}{k^2})(\frac{k-2}{k})=\frac{3}{k}-\frac{9}{k^2}+\frac{6}{k^3}$$
The maximum value of this probability occurs when $k=5$ and hence the most likely value of $k$ is $5$.

Comment: In part a), the probability is twice what you give, because there are two ways to assign the selected colors to the candies.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that either permutation was valid.

Comment: I'm sure this is the answer the examiner wanted, but it bothers me.  If "most likely" means "with highest probability" how are we to assign probabilities to $k?$  In part a), $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac3k-{3\over k^2}\right)=\infty$$ so we can't just normalize them.  Perhaps I'm becoming a Bayesian in my old age.

Comment: @saulspatz - see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/what-is-the-difference-between-likelihood-and-probability but the short short answer is each term in your summation is a prob value *in a different experiement* (different universe?) where the value of $k$ is different, so you can't add them.  This used to confuse me too... if that makes you feel better.  :)  Also, re: Bayesian, if you can imagine a magical prior distribution on all $k$ with equal probability (magical coz it doesn't exist), then that is about equivalent to the max-likelihood viewpoint.

Comment: @antkam Thanks you.  The accepted answer does clear it up for me.